# Printing integers in python list in correct orderly manner

Tags: python, list

I have this list from user input:

```
sun=[8,8,7,7,4,6,4,5,]
>>> sun.index(8)
0
>>> sun.index(7)
2
>>> sun.index(4)
4
```

Would like to write a program to print `"Impossible"`, because `4,5,6` are not in correct order in the list.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "4,5,6 are not in correct order in the list". What is the correct order?

Comment: What is the questions exactly?

Comment: On other hand , you could print yes if 4,5,6 were in that order on above list.

Answer (score 2):

print "Impossible" * (sun != sorted(sun))

Comment: I always learn new one-liners from reading this site.